# Predicting sparse time series data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, sparse

I have a dataset of a couple of EV charging stations (10 min frequency) over 1 year. This data consists of lots of 0s, since there is no continuous flow of cars coming to charge, but rather reoccurring charging events as peaks (for example from 7-9am seems to be a frequent charging timeframe when people are coming to the office).
I have also aggregated weather and weekday/holiday data to be used as features.

[image]

I now wish to predict the energy demand for a timeframe of 6h in the future.
So far I have tried SARIMA with terrible results, since the algorithm seems to be obscured by the sparse data.

I have tried different transformations (Box Cox, Normalization, Standardization), differencing, auto-arima for optimal parameters, so far no luck.

I am willing to try different machine learning as well as statistical algorithms.
**Does anyone have some recommendations as of what I can do to generate a moderatly accurate prediction with a sparse dataset?**

Answer (score 0):

One option is to model the problem as a [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) distribution . λ, the event rate, is the only parameter to estimate. Then the number of events timeframe can be estimated.